# problems with a popup in openlayes

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openstreetmap

I need to make permanent popup but only managed to make it show when a mouse event, i found an example but nothing to adapt achievement: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html

anyone can help me to make permanent the popup, Thanks.

```
var mapa;
OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
OpenLayers.ImgPath = "/openlayers/img/"
mapa = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
    controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
    ],
    theme: null
});
var osm  = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( " Open Street Map" );
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Ruta" );
$.each(info, function(i, data){
    var size   = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon   = new OpenLayers.Icon('/openlayers/img/data.png',size,offset);
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(data.long),parseFloat(data.lat));
    var proj_1 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var proj_2 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var EPSG   = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(EPSG, icon);
    markers.addMarker(marker);
    // popup
    marker.events.register("click", marker, function(e){
        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(data.idunidad,
                    marker.lonlat,
                    new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                    '<p>info in the popup, mouse event</p>',
                    null,true);
        popup.idunidad = data.idunidad;
        mapa.addPopup(popup);
        arrPopup.push(popup);
    });
});
var lonlat  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-74.075833,4.598056);
var proj_1  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var proj_2  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var centrar = lonlat.transform(proj_1,proj_2);
mapa.addLayers([osm,markers]);
mapa.setCenter(centrar, 5);
mapa.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use vector layers, you know this example?

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html

Comment: hello and thank you, if conosco the example, but the problem I have is that I'm not the best with OpenLayers, but with so many different examples, and the idea is to make permanent the popup in my code any more, as in my example and this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html urgent need a little help.

Comment: There are many ways of working...
"only managed to make it show when a mouse event" ... "permanent" ... "click" 
Really that is what you want. Help much store attributes in vector features...

Comment: hello, sorry but the truth, not how and do not really understand, and try in many ways and can not get the pupop remains visible, this code works if you do click the icon, and displays the popup, but I want permanent since the icon on the map, I would appreciate you to help me in my code as such. really thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's right, now I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'x' of null http://jsfiddle.net/vEJR8/1/ think it's because of the way it is written the coordinates.

Comment: ok I understand, I understand that it is on the vector, but if I need to delete then add another one and a new location, and identify the feature?

Comment: for example, after appearing the two, move to new position 6000000, 6000000

Comment: hi, try this look but I still get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'x' of null http://jsfiddle.net/vEJR8/2/

Comment: can you help me? but almost nothing to achieve

Comment: I do not understand the code you posted, are all the code? Why `markers` layer is used if it is empty? Why declares a `vectorLayer` does not add to the map?... Have you looked OL examples eg http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/?q=label not popups but maybe also serves you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vEJR8/2/ markers is defined on line 15, on line 16 the variable info[] is used on data, info is a private variable that has the latitude and longitude information, in the line 22 attempts to get the feature vector to enter an id in line 19 to delete and then recreate it with the same id, at run time I do this, I have now the error is on line 24, TypeError: Can not read property 'x' of null, everything is fine, just do not show everything in the sample code. Thank you.

Comment: You can not add a pupup before `mapa.setCenter`, the OL code will fail, and to call `mapa.setCenter` requires that the base layer is added to the map (so OSM)

Comment: I spent too much time in the comments of this question... Please see OL examples.

Comment: that was, thank you very much, I did not know these rules and solve the problem effectively.

regards